# Kubernetes: Cluster running but unresponsive to changes, cannot retrieve logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

I have an existing cluster running k8s version `1.12.8` on AWS EC2. The cluster contains several pods - some serving web traffic and others configured as scheduled CronJobs. The cluster has been running fine in it's current configuration for at least 6 months, with CronJobs running every 5 minutes.

Recently, the CronJobs simply stopped. Viewing the pods via `kubectl` shows all the scheduled CronJobs last run was at roughly the same time. Logs sent to AWS Cloudwatch show no error output, and stop at the same time `kubectl` shows for the last run.

In trying to diagnose this issue I have found a broader pattern of the cluster being unresponsive to changes, eg: I cannot retrieve logs or nodes via kubectl.

I deleted Pods in Replica Sets and they never return. I've set autoscale values on Replica Sets and nothing happens.

Investigation of the `kubelet` logs on the master instance revealed repeating errors, coinciding with the time the failure was first noticed:

```
I0805 03:17:54.597295 2730 kubelet.go:1928] SyncLoop (PLEG): "kube-scheduler-ip-x-x-x-x.z-west-y.compute.internal_kube-system(181xxyyzz)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"181xxyyzz", Type:"ContainerDied", Data:"405ayyzzz"}
        ...
E0805 03:18:10.867737 2730 kubelet_node_status.go:378] Error updating node status, will retry: failed to patch status "{\"status\":{\"$setElementOrder/conditions\":[{\"type\":\"NetworkUnavailable\"},{\"type\":\"OutOfDisk\"},{\"type\":\"MemoryPressure\"},{\"type\":\"DiskPressure\"},{\"type\":\"PIDPressure\"},{\"type\":\"Ready\"}],"conditions\":[{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2020-08-05T03:18:00Z\",\"type\":\"OutOfDisk\"},{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2020-08-05T03:18:00Z\",\"type\":\"MemoryPressure\"},{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2020-08-05T03:18:00Z\",\"type\":\"DiskPressure\"},{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2020-08-05T03:18:00Z\",\"type\":\"PIDPressure\"},{\"lastHeartbeatTime\":\"2020-08-05T03:18:00Z\",\"type\":\"Ready\"}]}}" for node "ip-172-20-60-88.eu-west-2.compute.internal": Patch https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-x-x-x-x.z-west-y.compute.internal/status?timeout=10s: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
...
E0805 03:18:20.869436 2730 kubelet_node_status.go:378] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "ip-172-20-60-88.eu-west-2.compute.internal": Get https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-172-20-60-88.eu-west-2.compute.internal?timeout=10s: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Running `docker ps` on the master node shows that both `k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager` and `k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler` containers were started 6 days ago, where the other k8s containers are at 8+ months.

**tl;dr**
A container on my main node (likely `kube-scheduler`, `kube-controller-manager` or both) died. The containers have come back up but are unable to communicate with the existing nodes - this is preventing any scheduled CronJobs or new deployments from being satisfied.

How can re-configure kubelet and associated services on the master node to communicate again with the worker nodes?

Comment: In this case you could start by checking the log output of the kubelets, that would be my first guess. See also: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs

Comment: @Blokje5 Thanks - I've added quite a lot of new findings above - any further help you're able to give is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on [Troubleshoot Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/)

Digging deeper into the cluster requires logging into the relevant machines. Here are the locations of the relevant log files. (note that on systemd-based systems, you may need to use `journalctl` instead)

**Master Nodes**

`/var/log/kube-apiserver.log` - API Server, responsible for serving the API

`/var/log/kube-scheduler.log` - Scheduler, responsible for making scheduling decisions

`/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log` - Controller that manages replication controllers

**Worker Nodes**

`/var/log/kubelet.log` - Kubelet, responsible for running containers on the node
`/var/log/kube-proxy.log` - Kube Proxy, responsible for service load balancing

Another way to get logs is to use `docker ps` to get `containerid` and then use `docker logs containerid`

If you have (which you should) a monitoring system setup using prometheus and Grafana you can check metrics such as high cpu load on API Server pods